# Swiper: Set custom slide to active

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) to show a slider with every month of the year.
It slides from left to right.

I now want to start with the current month on the left side.
If there are month before, they should be in the left offset.

I tried to give the `.swiper-slide` class the active class `.swiper-slide-active`:

```
<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active">
```

But that doesnt work.

In the docs I found no parameter to set a acive slide in the settings.
Is there any way to do this?

**Here's my current code:** https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/dydrLBP

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-months", {
    cssMode: false,
    slidesPerView: 3.5,
    spaceBetween: 16,
    activeIndex: 6,
    mousewheel: {
        forceToAxis: true,
    },
});
```

The `activeIndex: 6` doesn't work either. I'm not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `initialSlide`, `activeIndex` is just for getting the actual active index. But I think you shoud use `5` insted of `6` to start on sixth month, because first month starts with 1 and indexing starts from 0.

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-months", {
    initialSlide: 6,
    cssMode: false,
    slidesPerView: 3.5,
    spaceBetween: 16,
    mousewheel: {
        forceToAxis: true,
    },
});
```